# Sorting Vector in Ascending order and saving to a text file

Tags: java, sorting, text, vector, save

I have a Vector that needs to be sorted in Ascending order, as im still a beginner im finding slightly hard to make this work, I've been trying to do it with insertElementAt and compareTo, but  I didnt manage. Can anyone Help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  There's not enough information in your post.  First, you haven't shown your attempted implementation of a sorting algorithm.  Second, you haven't said what field in `Product` you would like to sort by (product code, unit price, phrase?).  All in all, we'll need a bit more effort from you before we can help. :)

Comment: Hint: Collections.sort() & Comparator

Comment: i have tried Collections.sort, but since i have never used it before i couldnt figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Are you really interested in using a `Vector`? It's obsolete in Java. *Vector is considered to be a legacy class* - [see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1037210).

Comment: Yes as my assignment requires me to use vectors and not an array.

Comment: out of following fields `String desc, code, phrase; double price;` on the basis of which field do you want to sort Products?

Comment: i want to sort in ascending based on code

Comment: @alestanis - How do you figure that's a duplicate? The base language is different (Java vs. C++)

Answer (score 0):

You should decide a criteria based on what you are sorting your vector. You can't just compare two objects, you should pick a "price" or "code", etc. and compare your objects based on that value

Comment: Yes i know, but i dont know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take:

1. Make your `Product` class implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. This way, you can implement the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method which is the base for the sorting operation. This method defines ordering, because it determines which element is *higher* and which one is *lower* by returning a positive `int`, zero or a negative `int`.
2. Implement your very own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). A comparator defines a comparation method that takes two elements as a base and compares them in the same way that `compareTo` does. The advantage here is that you can switch ordering criteria by ordering with a different `Comparator`.

Finally, the sorting can be performed by the use of any of the overloads of `Collections#sort` that takes your collection as an argument and a `Comparator` if you decide to use one.

Comment: I still dont understand how to use the compareTo method, I understand that i need to compare i and i+1, and if i+1 is smaller it replaces i.

Comment: @user1965046 That's the point. You implement it but you don't use it yourself. `Collections.sort` will base its sorting algorithm on it or in a `Comparator`, should you decide to implement one.

Comment: I have been lookingg at examples all day, i understand how it works I just dont know how to code it.

Comment: @user1965046 Implement the interface (`public class Product implements Comparable`) and then override the `compareTo` method. Then, define the ordering criteria (desc, code, phrase or price) and compare the values using `compareTo` for `String`s (it's already implemented) or simply substract the prices between themselves if you use price as the ordering factor (they're doubles, not wrappers, unless you use the wrapper `Double` you have no `compareTo` method there).

Comment: I still cant figure out the code, is it possible to help me out with the code or does that go against the rules of the forum?

Comment: @user1965046 It's not about rules but about yourself. You can't expect anyone to do your assignment for you, it simply breaks the purpose of trying and learning. Plus, if you were taking a look at examples all day you should have found one that resembles your case (I just googled the topic and found a detailed tutorial involving a list of Products).

Comment: can you share the link, because i didnt manage to fnd one similar to mine.

Comment: @user1965046 Check [this](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2005/12/08/sorting-a-vector-using-collections-sort/) out, hope it helps somehow if you're this lost.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Product class Sortable according to `code` . You can implement `Comparable` interface to your Product class and override `compareTo` method. Your `Product` class would look like this then:

```
import java.util.*;
class Product implements Comparable<Product>
{
    String desc, code, phrase;
    double price;

    public Product()
    {
        this.desc = "";
        this.code = ""; // later on irid jinbidel
        this. price = 0.0; 
        this.phrase = "";   
    }
    public Product(String desc, String code, String phrase, double price){
        this.desc = desc;
        this.code = code; // later on irid jinbidel
        this. price = price; 
        this.phrase = phrase;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return code;//+", "+desc+", "+price+", "+phrase+".";

    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Product obj) {
        return code.compareTo(obj.code);
    }
}
```

To Test if it is sorting Correctly here is simple Demo:

```
public class TestProduct
{
    public static void main(String[] st)
    {
        Vector<Product> v = new Vector<Product>();
        for (int i = 9 ; i > 0 ; i-- )
        {
            v.add(new Product("MyProduct",i+"Product","Good Product",34.5));
        }
        System.out.println("Before sorting");//Records inserted in decreasing order of code.
        System.out.println(v);
        Collections.sort(v);
        System.out.println("After sorting");//Records showing in increasing order of code.
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: but the output doesnt come sorted in ascending order with this code. or is there more i need to add?

Comment: @user1965046 : watch my edited answer.. To sort the `Vector` you need to call `Collections.sort(VectorObject)` explicitly..Which you haven't done in your code.